# How to style the default dragIndicator when dragging?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

Using RF 4.1 I am trying to style the default `dragIndicator` (the one used when none is defined). When I use a custom `dragIndicator`, I can style it using the class `rf-ind-drag`,  but the default `dragIndicator` only has the class `ui-draggable`.

The problem with `ui-draggable` is, that it is already set before dragging, so my component has the dragging style before I start dragging it.

How can I style the default `dragIndicator` or make the custom one look like the component that I am dragging (I drag tree nodes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does what I want, when I define the dragIndicator inside the treeNode.

```
<rich:treeNode type="FIELD" iconCollapsed="/images/field_icon.gif" iconExpanded="/images/field_icon.gif"
    iconLeaf="/images/field_icon.gif">
    <h:outputText value="#{node.nodeName}" />
    <rich:dragSource dragValue="#{node}" type="FIELD" dragIndicator="fieldIndicator" />
    <rich:dragIndicator id="fieldIndicator">
        <h:outputText value="#{node.nodeName}" />
    </rich:dragIndicator>
</rich:treeNode>
```

Answer (score 0):

All CSS classes of rich:dragIndicator are documented in the Developer Guide [1].

[1] http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.2.X/4.2.2.Final/Developer_Guide/en-US/html_single/#sect-Developer_Guide-Style_classes_and_skin_parameters-richdragIndicator